# Keyboard function shortcuts not working properly on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I didn't have this problem until pretty recently. I'm using an ASUS K53E laptop.

When I use the function keyboard shortcuts (ie. Function key + F1-12) the functions seem to be doing the opposite on a few keystroke inputs but then do their intended functions after those few keystrokes. For example, if I press fn + F11 (volume down) a few times, the volume will go up instead of down, but eventually after enough times of repeatedly pressing F11 it will start working normally and the volume will go down as it's supposed to.

If anyone could help and/or needs additional information to help, please let me know.